# How to get distance between waypoints in HERE API

Tags: here-api

I would like to know the distance between :

> waypoint0 - waypoint1  and  waypoint1 - waypoint2 .

Currently i am using the following request  :

```
    https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?
    mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&
    truckType=tractorTruck&
    maneuverAttributes=none&
    combineChange=true&
    routeAttributes=none,wp,sm,sh,no&
    linkAttributes=none&
    legAttributes=none&
    detail=1&
    alternatives=2&
    rollup=total,country&
    jsonattributes=41&
    waypoint0=geo!stopOver!53.55155000,9.99960000&
    waypoint1=geo!passThrough!45.97279231,4.73305852&
    waypoint2=geo!stopOver!41.15305000,-8.57573000
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would also like to get the toll costs between the waypoints.

Comment: to get the distance between two GPS coordinates you can use the Haversine formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try waypoint sequence API to get the distance between the waypoints.

```
https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json
?start=Berlin-Main-Station;52.52282,13.37011
&destination1=East-Side-Gallery;52.50341,13.44429
&destination2=Olympiastadion;52.51293,13.24021
&end=HERE-Berlin-Campus;52.53066,13.38511
&mode=fastest;car
&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response will look like -**

```
{
      "fromWaypoint": "waypoint0",
      "toWaypoint": "waypoint1",
      "distance": 7264,
      "time": 851,
      ...
    }
```

for more details kindly see the documentation-

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-simple-car.html